# Approximating large numbers of points to a Bezier curve

Tags: bezier

I have a large set (~500 points) of coordinates which are supposed to be part of a curve. I was interested to know if it is possible to approximate this curve (which I have in the form of coordinates) to a Bezier curve, perhaps a cubic Bezier. And if it is possible to get the four control points of that Bezier using some code.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in python, java, etc? Or just asking if it's mathematically possible?

Comment: Though I'd say I'm not yet even sure about it's mathematical feasibility.